# Flink Kafka : Expecting type to be a PojoTypeInfo

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

My customer class is already created using maven-avro plugin.When i try to run this program i am getting error as `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expecting type to be a PojoTypeInfo`

`[main] INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - class com.example.Customer does not contain a setter for field first_name`

`[main] INFO org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor - Class class com.example.Customer cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.` 
I am using java 8

My customer class created from maven avro plugin is of specific record type

Please help me i have spent last 5 days on this still not resolved

I tried 3 different Methods and i mentioned them as Method 1, Method 2 .. below

```
package com.example
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigException.Generic
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.createTypeInformation
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema


import java.util.Properties
object flink_kafka_avro extends App  {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val properties = new Properties
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092")
    properties.put("group.id", "customer-consumer-group-v1")
    properties.put("auto.commit.enable", "false")
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
    

    import org.apache.avro.Schema
    import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData


    val schema = ReflectData.get.getSchema(classOf[Customer])
    // Method 1 not working
    //val ss = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[Customer]("customer-avro", AvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(classOf[Customer]),properties)
    val schemaRegistryUrl = "http://localhost:8081"
    //Method 2
    val userKafkaReaderResult = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer[Customer]("customer-avro",
        ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(classOf[Customer],schemaRegistryUrl), properties).setStartFromEarliest())
    userKafkaReaderResult.print()
    //Method 3

    // I tried like this it is not working even

    //val strenew = FlinkKafkaConsumer[Customer]("test_topic", AvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(classOf[Customer]), properties).setStartFromEarliest
    //env.addSource(ss).print()
    env.execute()


}
```

My POM File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafkaavrov1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <properties>
        <avro.version>1.8.2</avro.version>
        <kafka.version>0.11.0.1</kafka.version>
        <confluent.version>3.3.1</confluent.version>
    </properties>

    <!--necessary to resolve confluent dependencies-->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-streaming-scala -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-avro-confluent-registry -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!--Only dependency needed for the avro part-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--dependencies needed for the kafka part-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>dd
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <stringType>String</stringType>
                            <createSetters>false</createSetters>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                            <fieldVisibility>private</fieldVisibility>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-sources/avro</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: as told in David's answer, you need a `SpecificRecordBase` base type in order to be recognized as such.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `Customer` extends `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase`, Flink won't see it as an Avro type, and will try to serialize it using its POJO serializer. And if that fails (as it does here) it will fall back to treating it as a generic type, and will use Kryo.

Comment: I have a similar issue where an auto generated Avro POJO class does extend `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase` but still get the PojoType error. Any ideas why? Please take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931874/flink-avro-error-expecting-type-to-be-a-pojotypeinfo

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by this line in POM:
false
Flink Avro util will check get/set method for each field within the class. If neither of them found, error will be thrown.

I fixed mine by set "createSetters=true".